# Gradle Release Plugin for functionalities like Maven release

Tags: gradle-plugin, maven-release-plugin, gradle-release-plugin

I am in the process of converting the existing maven project to Gradle for which I want to use alternative for maven release plugin. Mainly the functionality to remove snapshot and autoincrement by 1 once the release is cut.
I came across to use researchgate gradle-release-plugin but need to identify how can I use to this to achieve maven like functionality described above.

I am trying for the first time and gone through below URL:
https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To automatically remove "-SNAPSHOT" and increment the version you can do `gradle release -Prelease.useAutomaticVersion=true` and also additionally `-Prelease.releaseVersion=1.0 -Prelease.newVersion=1.1-SNAPSHOT` to specify the next versions.

If you have a different versioning scheme you can change it too and with a regex + closure specify how to handle it. Check the "versionPatterns" for this.

Answer (score 2):

It is called [Maven Publish Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html):

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
}
```

When building with Jenkins, one can also pull in the build-number:

```
project.ext.set('build_number', System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER") ?: "0")
```